# How to combine 2 VBA functions based on condition of 1 function?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset where contact information and names are correlated to companies that the individual has worked for. 1 individual can be associated with many companies. I want to consolidate information of the individuals but keep information on the different company names.

I have a VBA function that can remove duplicates of rows (name and contact info) and another VBA function that can merge two separate cells (company names) into 1 merged cell. The data isn't sorted by any particular field.

I would like to create a function that will remove duplicates of rows AND THEN merge the company name cells BUT ONLY FOR individuals that have duplicate rows removed (meaning that the individual is associated with more than 1 company).

Thanks for any help!

Sample of raw data format:

[image]

this is the function and result of VBA function 1:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
'UpdatebyExtendoffice20160918
 
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xCol As Long
    Dim xrg As Range
    Dim xl As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xrg = Application.InputBox("Select a range:", "Kutools for Excel", _
                                    ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.AddressLocal, , , , , 8)
 
    xRow = xrg.Rows.Count + xrg.Row - 1
    xCol = xrg.Column
    'MsgBox xRow & ":" & xCol
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For xl = xRow To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(xl, xCol) = Cells(xl - 1, xCol) Then
            Cells(xl, xCol) = ""
        End If
    Next xl
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Function 2 is below and the module just concatenates and merges cells, but I don't know how to write a function that will only apply where the individual has had duplicate rows removed (meaning that individual is associated with multiple companies).

```
Sub MergeCells()
    Dim xJoinRange As Range
    Dim xDestination As Range
        
    Set xJoinRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Highlight source cells to merge", Type:=8)
    Set xDestination = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Highlight destination cell", Type:=8)
    temp = ""
    For Each Rng In xJoinRange
        temp = temp & Rng.Value & " "
    Next
    xDestination.Value = temp
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @analyst2020 and welcome to SO. Please provide the code for the first function and someone might be able to help you update it so that it performs the whole task. I suspect you merely have to add a line or 2 to your first function to achieve what you want. Also please mention any assumptions such as the data is sorted by email prior to running the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this differently and use Power Query, available in Excel 2010+.

Power Query as a "Group By" method where you can select the columns you want to group by -- in your case it would be all the columns except the **Company** column.  You can then concatentate the company column using linefeeds, and obtain the result you desire.

- `Data --> Get & Transform Data --> From Table/Range`
- Select all the columns except Company and `Group By`
- The Operation is `All Rows`

[image]

- Add Custom Column (to split out the company names with formula:

  - `Table.Column([Grouped],"Company")`

[image]

- Select the Double-headed arrow at the top of the custom column

  - Extract values from list
  - Use the line feed for the separator `#(lf)`
- Close and Load to

You may have to do some custom formatting for the phone number, and also set Word Wrap for the company column.

Here is the generated **MCode**:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Email", type text}, {"Phone", Int64.Type}, {"First Name", type text}, {"Last Name", type text}, {"Company", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Email", "Phone", "First Name", "Last Name"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Email=text, Phone=number, First Name=text, Last Name=text, Company=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Company", each Table.Column([Grouped],"Company")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Company", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "#(lf)"), type text})
in
    #"Extracted Values"
```

And here are the results:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a recommendation on how this PowerQuery can be automated, apologies that I'm not familiar with it? My intention in using VBA was so that I can hand the code off to other parties and they can use it for future cases of the same data.

Comment: @analyst2020 Power Query has been a part of Excel since 2016, and available as a free Microsoft provided add-in since 2010.  To distribute it, you distribute the workbook containing the code and the table where other parties would enter the data.  How were you going to distribute your VBA code?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I was thinking that with the VBA I can just give it to my partner and they can save it once and run it to all their future workbooks. I'm trying to reduce as much work for them as possible b/c they're not proficient in excel. Maybe it's possible to record this process via macro though.

Comment: @analyst2020 You could probably set this up as a template.